# CSS: Margin-top when parent's got no border

Tags: css, border, margin

As you can see in [this picture](http://i30.tinypic.com/v4utxj.png), I've got an orange `div` inside a green `div` with no top border. The orange `div` has a `30px` top margin, but it's also pushing the green `div` down. Of course, adding a top border will fix the issue, but I need the green `div` to be top borderless. What could I do?

```css
.body {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    width: 120px;
    height: 112px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.body .container {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Top</div>
<div class="body">
    <div class="container">Box</div>
</div>
<div class="foot">Bottom</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the desired effect?  Do you want text within the orange container to appear 30 pixels from the top or do you want the top of the orange container to appear 30 pixels below the top of the green container?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315738/unexpected-margin-with-very-simple-html

Comment: Might be more appropriate for http://doctype.com/

Comment: Related: [clear and collapse fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007322/clear-fix-and-uncollapse-margins-with-css-without-side-effects).

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You could add `overflow:auto` to `.body` to prevent margin-collapsing. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: woot, just saved me from going mad with my disappearing margin!

Comment: I had the same problem, was driving me insane as I do not wish to have a border, this fixed my issue, thanks for the info, and the link helps explains why this happens.

Comment: Margin collapsing seems a strange thing to have as a default, anyone got a good example of when you would want to use it?

Comment: Good doc on margin collapsing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing

Answer (score 9):

What you experience is margin collapsing. The margin doesn't specify an area around an element, but rather the minimum distance between elements.

As the green container doesn't have any border or padding, there is nothing to contain the margin of the orange element. The margin is used between the top element and the orange element just as if the green container would have the margin.

Use a padding in the green container instead of a margin on the orange element.

Answer (score 1):

Use `padding` instead of `margin`:

```
.body .container {
    ...
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work in your case, but I just solved this with the following CSS properties

```
#element {
    padding-top: 1px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

`#element` was being pushed down because it's first child element had a `margin-top: 30px`. With this CSS, it now works as expected :) Not sure if it'll work for every case, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add `padding-top: 30` on the green box, use relative positioning on the orange box with `top: 30px`, or float the orange box and use the same `margin-top: 30px`.

Answer (score 0):

You read this document:
[Box model - Margin collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

CSS

```
.body {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
    width: 120px;
    height: 112px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.body .container {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how hackish this sounds, but how about adding a transparent border?