# LI margin does not affect UL element

Tags: html, css, list, margin

If i'll put margin-top to the first list item(LI), then margin is outside of ul.

Same thing for last item and margin-bottom.
But margin-left/margin right works as expected..

Why is that and is that fixable?

See :[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/itimeheke/Meapn/)

Cheers

Comment: That is not how you make a `<ul>`, look here for a proper one: http://jsfiddle.net/Meapn/1/

Comment: Mine works also fine. Quiestion is about margin-top, not how to code ul.

Comment: It works fine yes, but you should still try to use proper mark up, especially if you are going to ask for help troubleshooting issues

Comment: @andy What is wrong with <br> in <li> ? pretty sure it is VALID :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a <br> in a <li>, but you want to create a list with list items, so why not use the tags that were created specifically for your purpose?

Comment: I had one item, and questin was about that. But okay, i'll get your point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put

```
overflow : auto;
```

in the parent ul.

See [Margin-Top push outer div down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680478/margin-top-push-outer-div-down)

Comment: That is excaly what i was looking for! Cheers mate!

Comment: But as Scott said, padding could be what you're looking for too.

Comment: Jup +1 for that, but he posted a solution, you posted an answer to my question. And with your solution i dont have to change my code :)

Answer (score 2):

Your ul contains only one element witch actually has working margin.
You should replace this code

```
<li>
    This is a test<br>
    This is a test<br>
    This is a test<br>
    This is a test<br>
</li>
```

With:

```
<li>This is a test</li>
<li>This is a test</li>
<li>This is a test</li>
<li>This is a test</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing between a ul tag and an li tag. They essentially follow each other. What you want is padding in the ul, not margin in the li.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Meapn/4/)