# top margin is not working inside div

Tags: html, css, margin

I have two divs..

**CSS**

```
#content {
    background: url('../images/bg.jpg') no-repeat left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 811px;
}
#welcome {
    background: #fff;
    width: 600px;
    height: 50px;
    color: #000;
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="welcome">
        this is welcome
    </div>
</div>
```

The margin is moving parent div, not inside one. I also tried to give padding to parent div, same thing. How to solve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Margin-Top push outer div down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680478/margin-top-push-outer-div-down)

Comment: add a float element for example `float: left;`

Comment: This is classic example of collapsing margins... see reference posted by @nalply

Comment: And this question gets the same answers as its duplicate... :-/

Comment: I suspect that if you know about collapsing margins, you would probably not have this issue in the first place.  If you have the issue, but you don't know the name of it, you can't find the answer because you don't know which question to ask... a Catch-22 situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding `overflow:hidden;` to the parent

```
#content{
  background:url('../images/bg.jpg') no-repeat left;
  width:100%;
  height:811px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border: 1px solid; /*remove*/
}
#welcome {
  border: 1px solid; /*remove*/
  background:#fff;
  width:600px;
  height:50px;
  color:#000;
  margin-top:200px;
}
```

here you have the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/JmBj9/

(i added the borders so you can see it)

Answer (score 1):

Try having overflow:auto;

```
#content{
background:url('../images/bg.jpg') no-repeat left;
width:100%;
height:811px;
overflow:auto;
}
#welcome {
background:#fff;
width:600px;
height:50px;
color:#000;
margin-top:200px;
}
```