# Why is setting the top-margin of this child element pushing its parent container down with it?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs:

```
<div id="headercontainer" data-type="background" data-speed="5"> 
    <div id="headersubcontainer">
        <h1>Simple and Cost Effective Web Solutions</h1>  
    </div> 
</div>

<div id="teamcontainer" data-type="background" data-speed="5"> 
    <div id="teamsubcontainer"> 
        <h1>Developed by a dedicated team</h1> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

both have 100% widths and heights of 800px. The first heading I have set a top-margin: of 160px. Instead of moving the header lower into its parent div, it moves the parent div down with it as you can see in this picture:

[image: webpage]

Here is my relevant css:

```
h1{
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: $header-font-stack; 
    font-weight: 100;
    width: 400px;
}

#headercontainer{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 800px;
    background-image: image-url("background.jpg");
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#headercontainer h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 160px;
    color: #610B21;
}
```

Using a padding works obviously, but I would like to be more proper and use a margin. How can set a top margin and move the heading lower into the container without moving the container with it?

Comment: I think because the parent height is set to a constand value. Margins and paddings are counted plus the heights and widths.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Margin-Top push outer div down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680478/margin-top-push-outer-div-down)

Answer (score 28):

This is due to [**margin collapsing**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing):

> Top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed)
>   into a single margin whose size is the largest of the margins combined
>   into it, a behavior known as margin collapsing.

This is resulting in the parent element reverse-inheriting the child element top margin.

You can prevent this by adding `&nbsp;` before the child element

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/y3mS6/)

....or applying any of the below to the parent:

1. float: left / right
2. position: absolute
3. display: inline-block

Adding `display:inline-block;` to the parent likely being the preference if it is set to have a width to 100%

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/y3mS6/1/)

Comment: where exactly do i add this? and what is it doing exactly?

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/y3mS6/, I@d likely go with one of the latter 3 settings on the parent however

Comment: Also have a look at: http://960development.com/understand-css-margins-collapsing/

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer, its been more than 1 year

Comment: according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1939980/286685) you can also set: 4. `overflow: auto`, or 5: `margin:-1px; padding:1px`.

Answer (score 1):

just use `box-sizing: border-box;` on the parent and set the `padding` there instead of `margin-top`. It will help you keep consistent spacing on all sides anyways

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EbSN7/)

Answer (score 1):

Just add some top-padding to the parent element. even 1px and it will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually argue that this answer is better:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49075574/2387316

Yes, I know it's my own answer, but I think it's important that we don't add random bits of padding, change box-sizing for no reason, add spurious elements to the DOM, or change display/padding simply to fix a display issue. Those solutions all cause problems on their own: SEO is worse, unpredictable box-sizing behavior when trying to do something else, annoyance caused by positioning and display changes, etc. This solution is good for SEO, is scalable, and has no other tangible effect when trying to do other things with your elements.

Comment: Much better, agree that anything else changes the DOM in weird ways.