# Compositional CSS?

Tags: css, composition

I've just spent quite some time chasing a gap like the one in this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/eEpmihlym2oCAiftnxRx?p=preview). The problem wasn't that simple. It's a dynamically created page and some component having `margin-bottom` happened to be displayed last inside of `.main`.

Before I blame CSS, I wonder, what's the proper way for styling such an (old-school) bordered design? I mean something what doesn't break when an unknown component gets put inside?

Comment: Are you just trying to have text in the top and bottom borders?

Comment: @Dennis Sure, I need text there. Currently, everything works, but I want to do it in a way it doesn't break again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `overflow:auto;` to your main class is a simple one-line fix.

See - [Margin-Top push outer div down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680478/margin-top-push-outer-div-down)

Comment: I was googling before and I'd never come to the idea that it's margin collapsing. Chromium just shows a gap with no reason at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `!important`in your css,when you get unknown margin or padding,like

```
.tagclass{
    margin:0!important;
    padding:0!important;
}
```

It will raise the priority of margin:0 and padding:0,clear the gap.