# The margin of h1 tag in HTML pushed its container down

Tags: html, css, margin

Just look at the picture below. I don't know why the header (blue block) has gone down a little bit. I mean, the blue block should exactly touch the end of the content area of the browser. Some people told me that is because of the margin of h1. But I think this margin can only cause h1 to go down a little bit inside the blue block instead of making the entire blue block go down. Who can help me? Thanks a lot!

[image]

Sorry, the code is now added below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>just for test</title>
<style>
    body,html {
        margin: 0;
    }

    header {
        background-color: blue;
        height: 200px;
        width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
    }

    h1 {
        color: white;

    } 

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Why does it have to be like this?</h1>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to remove it and See what happens

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: Margin controls the spacing outside of your div, padding controls the spacing inside. Remove the margin from the H1 tag and you'll be set.

Comment: It's probably `padding` on `h` or `height` of that blue div

Comment: If you include the HTML and CSS, someone might be able to help you.

Comment: Probably the old "collapsing margins" thing - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680478/margin-top-push-outer-div-down

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example for you.

The following code returns these results:

[image: Margins]

```
<h1 class="nomargins">Testing 1</h1>
<h1 class="margins">Testing 2</h1>
```

---

```
.margins {
  width: 500px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:#0000ff;
  float:left;
}

.nomargins {
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color:#ff0000;
  float:left;
}
```

Notice how the only difference is the color and the margins.

Answer (score 0):

It's a margin collapse issue. **h1** tag which contains some text within it and wrapped within the container given by header. now **h1** tag is not getting its `margin-top` inside the container and it pulls whole container down by its default margin because of margin collapse issue *(because margin-top of **h1** tag is collapsed to 0)*. If you say h1 should have margin inside the container then you need to use either `padding,border,display:inline-block` or `overflow: auto` property inside `header {}`

After giving any one property from above list you can prevent margin collapse of **h1** tag and the text contained by **h1** tag will have margin inside container and will get justice so after this **h1** tag's margin will not be compromised.

I see, you have given `padding` but with 0 value, so it won't work. You have to give some value to it.