# CSS3: Margin of succeeding sibling has influence on preceeding sibling - why?

Tags: html, css

I have created a HTML5 `<header>` element which I want to stick to the top of the page. Following that header, a `<section>` element is supposed to display content.

For the `section` element to be aligned to the bottom of the header I have assigned it a `margin-top: 4em` CSS rule, which results in a strange effect: The `header` element is now displayed with a top margin of 4em, too:

https://jsfiddle.net/n5vzgLme/1/

I have tested this with several browsers. They all display the same effect.

When I add any arbitrary text to the body (e.g. "xx" in front of the `<header>` element) everything works fine. But when I then delete the text again, the odd behaviour re-occurs.

Why does this happen? AFAIK, the `header` element should not be influenced by styles of a succeeding element.

Comment: Its not the margin that's creating this effect. Its because of position:fixed. If you add a top property as {top:0}, the issue would go away.

Comment: I see. But I can't find any definition for this odd behaviour in the spec. Why is it influenced by the succeeding sibling?

Comment: Why? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680478/margin-top-push-outer-div-down

Comment: position:fixed; cause this problem. Add top:0; to fix the issue

Comment: Ah, I see. The collapsing margin issue seems to cause a number of other unexpected results, too. So will a body height of 100% only work if there's a border defined, for instance. @Paulie_D: Would you like to create an answer so I can award my vote to it?

Comment: No need...You should be setting `top:0` to the header anyway as it is position fixed. I will close this question as a duplicate of the linked one....