# Margin-top doesn't work as intended

Tags: html, css, margin

Please look at the following example: https://jsfiddle.net/9wbm179c/

The `margin-top:50px;` is making this ugly gap between **body** and `.outter`. Just read the code and this message again: between **body** and `.outter`... Isn't it should be making the gap between **.inner** and `.outter`?

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #777;
}

.outter {
  background: #099;
  text-align: center;
}

.inner {
  background: #ff0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div class="inner">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Margin-Top push outer div down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680478/margin-top-push-outer-div-down)

Comment: Can you please elaborate your issue? What i can see is difference between outter and inner is because of inner is having margin:0 auto; Please clarify your question.

Comment: [How to disable margin-collapsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing)

Comment: thanks folks! I was goin nuts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is called "margin collapse." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

> **Parent and first/last child** - If there is no border, padding, inline content, block_formatting_context created or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

You can address it a number of ways. One way is by using `overflow:hidden;` on the parent element `.outter`. You could also use `padding-top: 50px` on `.outter` instead of `margin-top` on `.inner`

```css
html,body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
body {
  background:#777;
}
.outter {
  background:#099;
  text-align:center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
  background:#ff0;
  width:400px;
  height:150px;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div class="inner">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, pal!