# margin from heading pushes div down

Tags: html, css

Can anyone explain why the div is being pushed down?  It seems like the top heading margin should push against the top of the div, not the browser window.

Wrapping another div around the div makes no difference.

But if I add *padding-top:1px;* to the div the problem goes away!

[one div](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/637134/hmm.png)

[fixed with padding](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/637134/hmm_withpadding.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `overflow:auto` to the parent element.

[CSS: Margin-top when parent's got no border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394724/css-margin-top-when-parents-got-no-border)

You can also use `overflow:hidden`. Using the `overflow` attribute on a parent element will also clear inner floats making `clear:both` not necessary.

Comment: thank you! I knew there was a post on this same topic but I couldn't find it!

Answer (score 3):

## Note:

This is a new answer to this question because [margin on element moves the whole page down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51595532/margin-on-element-moves-the-whole-page-down) was marked as a duplicate of this question, but I don't feel the accepted answer explains *why* this is happening, so here is a more detailed explanation of why you sometimes have a parent element have an odd, unexplained gap if the first child has a collapsed margin.

## Answer:

This is because of the [Block Formatting Context](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) (Also [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)).  basically what you're seeing is collapsing margins in action.  Collapsing margins are supposed to help collapse text based elements together so you don't have doubled up margins on things like paragraphs and headings, but the problem is that it's collapsing the paragraph to the parent causing the parent to effectively adopt the paragraph's margin:

> **Parent and first/last child**
> If there is no border, padding, inline part, block formatting context created, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block; or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.
> *[Mastering margin collapsing - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)*

One solution to your problem would be to create a new Block Formatting Context on the parent.  You can do this easily be adding `overflow: auto` to the parent.  It's likely that the parent element doesn't have a set height, so it shouldn't affect the document visually.  All it will do is create a new context that will cause the margin of the first child to be contained in the parent.