# margin on element moves the whole page down

Tags: html, css

The margin of an `h2` element in my page is displacing the whole `body` down.
This doesn't seem normal as the h2 element is contained in a `div` container.

How can I fix this ?

[image]

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Add `margin: 0;` to that elements CSS.

Comment: Try using padding instead of margin to your h2 element

Comment: @Lev this question was marked as a duplicate as I was submitting my answer.  Basically what you're experiencing is collapsing margins where the parent element is adopting the margin of your `h2`.  I've added a more detailed explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51595877/854246

Answer (score -1):

Put this at the top of your css file:

```
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
{
```