# Child div influencing parent div?

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to do is give a div `margin-top: 30px;` But it seems to be moving the whole page 30px down, as opposed to only that div. It is like the child div is influencing the parent div?

Any suggestions?

Html:

```
   <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BBcolForum.master.cs" Inherits="BBcolForum.BBcolForum" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" />    
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">

  <div class="header" style="margin-top:0px;">
  <h1 style="color:Aqua; margin-top:30px;">Student Forum</h1>
  </div>

    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">



        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>



    </form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS;

```
body 
{
    background-image:url('/img/blue_back.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;

}

#content
{
    background-color:White;
    width: 800px;
    height:900px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;   

}

.header
{
    border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
    height:100px;    
    color:Blue;



}
```

Comment: It's called *margin collapse*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what's happening, yes.  A direct-child of an element with margin-top will also push the parent element.  As a really easy/quick fix, have you considered using padding instead?

Failing that, you can use overflow: auto on the parent according to [this previous discussion on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680478/margin-top-push-outer-div-down), and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394724/css-margin-top-when-parents-got-no-border).

Comment: Ah ok, \nd no I am new to css so could you please provide me with an example of how padding works in this situation?

Comment: Ah never mind I have solved it using the padding you suggested thankyou +1

Comment: @user2413519 if any answer was helpful and solved the problem you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `padding:0.01px` to the container. This will have no visual effect, but it will cause the margin to be applied in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

It's the margin on the `<h1>`. This always seemed counter intuitive to me. You can fix it by putting `overflow: auto;` on the container or changing the `h1`s margin to padding.

Answer (score 0):

You must change

```
<h1 style="color:Aqua; margin-top:30px;">Student Forum</h1>
```

to

```
<h1 style="color:Aqua; padding-top:30px;">Student Forum</h1>
```

margin applies the space outside the object while padding applies it inside.