# HTML not letting me add a top margin

Tags: html, css, margin

I've got some simple HTML code in which I am building the basic layout for a simple website.

I am trying to position the red bar to be vertically centered inside the green area. For some reason, it will not move down when I add a top margin. I've been trying to figure out why for a half hour - so frustrating!

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hut9M/

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Basic</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="milestone">
      <div id="milestonecontent">
          <div id="event">
           </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
#body{
  background-color: #e9eaed;
}

#milestone{
  width: 512px;
  height: 137px;
  background-color: blue;

}

#milestonecontent{
  width: 512px;
  height: 104px;
  background-color: green;
}
#event{
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 512px;
  height: 58px;
  background-color: red;

}
.actions{
  border-top: 1px solid #e9eaed;
  position: relative;
  width: 512px;
  height: 33px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Also you have a style "`#body`" but no id for `body` element - remove the "`#`" in CSS or add "`id="body"` to the `body` element if you want that style to be applied to `body element`

Comment: PLease check my edited answer where the real problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it an inline-block element as @AfromanJ suggested or you could:

2) add a padding-top to the wrapping element `#milestonecontent`

3) add a 1px or more transparent `border: 1px solid transparent;` to the wrapping element `#milestonecontent` .....but the

## **REAL SOLUTION**

is to add a `overflow:auto` to the wrapping element #milestonecontent

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Hut9M/12/

**Code:**

```
#milestonecontent{
  width: 512px;
  height: 104px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Solved also in here: [CSS: Margin-top when parent's got no border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394724/css-margin-top-when-parents-got-no-border)

Comment: Can you explain why this is the "REAL solution"?

Comment: Because other solutions are workarounds - you explicitly wanted to set a margin-top/bottom to your current child-element. Setting parent's padding changes its original size. Setting a border gives extra space. Setting an inline-block behaviour is the least-workaround but still makes your element inline-block - now it is a full width element so it does not matter, however if it would matter if the width would be bigger than the parent's one. So finally overflow: auto; is more of an "setting" how the margins should be handled - to be handled as you expect. Hope it is clear :)

Comment: *inline-block - if the element's width would be of course smaller than the parent's width... inline-blocks dont have line breaks after them => it can be solved by adding a `<br>` but why would you do that when you can just have a block-only element :)

Comment: Also if you want to center it dynamicly I would recommend giving a parent alement a position relative and to your centered box absolute position and left: 50%, top: 50%, margin-left: -Width/2; margin-top: -Height/2; (margins are negative pixels).

Answer (score 1):

You can add `display: inline-block;` to your  `#event` DIV.

```
#event {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 23px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hut9M/2/)**

Comment: It worked! Can you explain why?

Comment: Row/inline element is considered as something that is the inner content of the wrapping element - so there is no margin-collapse happening - unlike block elements where child-element-margin collapses with the wrapping-element-margin.

Answer (score 0):

A block element like `div` has `width:auto` by default. you can give `padding-top` to parent `milestonecontent` and `margin:0 auto;` to `event` container which will keep'em centered across all resolutions.

a little glimpse of what i have modified,

```
#milestonecontent{
  height: 104px;
  padding-top:20px;
  background-color: green;
}

#event{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 58px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hut9M/11/).