# Element changes place when position fixed applied

Tags: javascript, css

When I apply `position: fixed` with Javascript my element moves a few pixels down and gets fixed in another position, some pixels down, instead of just staying where is was.

**Why is this?**

```
// html
<div id="container">
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</div>

// CSS
#container {
    height: 2000px;
}
#myDiv {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #88a;
}

// Javascript
myDiv.style.position = 'fixed';
```

I find this behaviour at least in Chrome and FF.

**http://jsfiddle.net/bSM8h/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply `position:fixed`, also do:

```
pin.addEventListener('click', function () {
    myDiv.style.position = 'fixed';
    myDiv.style.top = '50px';
    myDiv.style.marginTop = '0';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bSM8h/2/

*edit*

By default browsers do `body{padding:5px;}` that is why a good idea is to [html5boilerplate your css's](http://html5boilerplate.com/)

*end edit*

For some reason [(see explanation here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1394798/2119863), margin-top also pushed the container with it. Once applied `position:fixed`, the container sprung back to the top of the page (lost the margin) and was positioned 5px from the top of page.

**before `position:fixed`**

[image]

**after `position:fixed`**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Yes I am most interested in the "_For some reason_" part you mentioned. This problem does not happen when I reset the body for example: http://jsfiddle.net/bSM8h/3/

Comment: 100% on the nose! :) By default body has a `padding of 5px`. So the #container is positioned 5px from the top of page (see img2). That's why its ALWAYS a good idea to use `normalize/reset css`

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

This will prevent the extra padding added by the browser defaults.